# Object.Nosuchmethod error in stream property of streambuilder in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm struggling with a strange behaviour in a streamBuilder it can't launch the stream I got the error is :  >When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

## 0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

## 1      _UserCardState.build (package:flutter_firebase_app1/screens/home/userCard.dart:25:45)

The getter 'uid' was called on null.

which is the line : stream: DatabaseService(uid:this.user.uid).currentUser,

here is the code

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: DatabaseService(uid:user.uid).currentUser,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        print('snapshot : '+snapshot.connectionState.toString());
        print('user uid : '+user.uid);//working correctly so user is not null ?

        if(snapshot.hasData){ ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's telling you that `user` is null and therefore you cannot call the uid getter on it. You need to check to see why user is null.

Comment: I know but adding a print('user uid : '+user.uid); after is working ans print the uid... see my last edit

Comment: Can you please share more of your code, with all the parts that might be relevant to the question?

Comment: yes, here is the gist : https://gist.github.com/laTruffe79/d35af916eb6b051ca4552dd2881a3e44 thanks

Comment: @Brian85 I getting the same error while trying to fetch data, plz provide any solution if you know

Answer (score 0):

"NoSuchMethodErrors X was called on null" issues usually occur when the variable where the method was called may have yet to be initialized. From the snippets you've provided, make sure that `user` has been initialized. The logs indicates that `user` is null and throws and error when trying to fetch `uid`.